# Android SDK on Debian linux has blank windows

Tags: java, linux, debian, android-sdk-tools

Windows show like this:[image: The grey is the android 'setup' wizard]

Thinking it might be OpenJDK's fault, I downloaded Java SE JDK and pointed the run script to it. This did not appear to help.

Not sure what information to provide, other than being on debian jessie, using awesomewm, and:

```
~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: How do you start it? What is your operation system (version)?

Answer (score 2):

Leaving this up just in case someone stumbles on it. Apparently java, in many forms, has problems with a few wms. Awesomewm included. One needs to export a 'nonparenting' variable:

```
 export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
```

Maybe someone will come along and offer a more fulfilling answer to this problem.